# Overwrite Not Working

Tags: python, gis, overwrite, arcpy

I've seen other threads on here touching upon the issue I'm having, but none of them either apply to my problem or provide a solution, so I thought I'd post a new thread.

Basically, I'm creating a script that runs weekly and updates a shapefile (technically, it updates the 8 files associated with a shapefile, including the CPG) by converting a feature class to a shapefile. Currently I have it set to delete the existing files and then re-export them, but I'd rather have them be overwritten. For whatever reason, I can't get it to overwrite; it just creates the same files with "_1" appended to the end. Where am I going wrong? Thanks!

```
import arcpy, os
from arcpy import env
import time
import smtplib

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

connStr = "D:\Jobs\BSA-GIS-Shapefiles\Connections\GIS_Enterprise.sde"
outWrkSpc = "\\\gis\gisdata\BSA_Shapes"

inputParcels = "GISEnterprise.EOWNER.CParcel"
inputParcelAnnoAddr = "GISEnterprise.EOWNER.cParcel_Anno_Address"
inputPlats = "GISEnterprise.EOWNER.cPlat"

shpParcels =  "CParcel.shp"
shpParcelAnnoAddr =  "cParcel_Anno_Address.shp"
shpPlats =  "cPlat.shp"


env.workspace = outWrkSpc

try:
    arcpy.Delete_management(shpParcels)
    arcpy.Delete_management(shpParcelAnnoAddr)
    arcpy.Delete_management(shpPlats)



    arcpy.FeatureClassToShapefile_conversion(os.path.join(connStr,     
    inputParcels),outWrkSpc)
    arcpy.FeatureClassToShapefile_conversion(os.path.join(connStr
    ,inputParcelAnnoAddr), outWrkSpc)
    arcpy.FeatureClassToShapefile_conversion(os.path.join(connStr
    ,inputPlats), outWrkSpc)
```

I know those last lines shouldn't be split; they aren't in my code, I was just having trouble formatting in the post.

Comment: Please be aware that there is a [gis.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using FeatureClassToShapefile, I would use [CopyFeatures](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/copy-features.htm), so you can explicitly specifiy the output's name (not just the output workspace) and it will be overwritten:

```
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(os.path.join(connStr, inputParcels), os.path.join(outWrkSpc, shpParcels))
```

[Feature Class to Feature Class](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/conversion-toolbox/feature-class-to-feature-class.htm) is another perfectly suitable here too.

Both will accept shapefiles as input and/or output.

As stated in the help page for [Feature Class To Shapefile](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/conversion-toolbox/feature-class-to-shapefile.htm) (which is supposed to be used to process multiple input shapefiles in one step):

> If the output shapefile already exists in the Output Folder, a number
>   will be appended to the end to make the shapefile name unique (for
>   example, rivers_1.shp).

Comment: I'm trying to export a GDB feature class to a shapefile not inside a GDB; won't the copy features try to copy as a GDB feature class?

Comment: I'm also just curious as to what I'm doing wrong with the overwrite process. I may need it for a future problem.

Comment: So using the Feature Class to Feature Class operation will allow overwriting files, but the Feature Class to Shapefile operation will not? Is that the gist of what you're saying?